# How to track a user clicking on a link to a document

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to keep track of when my user clicks on a link to a pdf document. I want to store this click as a `view` in an already existing `views` table in my sqlite database but I am unsure how I can register that a link to a document has been clicked on.

In the HTML, this is how I refer to the document which is in table format:

`<td><a href="/static/resumes/{{row[2]}}">{{row[2]}}</a></td>`

I'm using python with flask so I think I could normally make a function for that url and then just add to the views table with the `session['user']` whenever that document is viewed, BUT these documents are user created and and will have random names so I'm not sure how I can account for that since I am just opening up a pdf document.

Here is an example of how I would like the python code to work(may or may not be helpful):

```
@app.route('/Employer/foo')
def updateView():
    addUserToView(session['user'])
    return render_template('foo.pdf')
```

Again I'm just not sure how to keep track of the pdf link

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that in that example:

```
<td><a href="/static/resumes/{{row[2]}}">{{row[2]}}</a></td>
```

`row[2]` is the document name ? What you could do is change that URL to something like: `/tracking/resumes/{{row[2]}}` and then, in your flask app, you create the `tracking` route:

```
@app.route('/tracking/resumes/<document_name>')
def tracking_resume_view(document_name):
    addUserToView(session['user'], document_name)
    redirect(url_for('static', filename='resume/{document_name}'.format(document_name)))
```

The idea is to have an intermediary dynamic page that will track / save the view and then redirect to the static content.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i had already solved my problem before I saw the reply as posted above but our methods seem very close

Answer (score 0):

Is what I ended up going with as the correct method

```
@app.route('/static/resumes/<path:filename>')
def addView(filename):
    adb.addViewEmployer(filename, session['username'])
    return send_from_directory('static/resumes/', filename)
```